# How to delete all image placeholder powerpoint with vsto powerpoint

Tags: vb.net, vsto, powerpoint

I'm try making an Add-in for PowerPoint 2019.  I want to delete only images on a slide in PowerPoint. im make button on ribbon when im click button all image deleted.

```
 Sub DeleteAllPictures()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim PPSlide As Slide
    For Each PPSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
 PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(1).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(2).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(3).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(4).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(5).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(6).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(7).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(8).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(9).Delete
        PPSlide.Shapes.Placeholders(10).Delete
            Next 
End Sub
```

previously I removed all image using vba macro and it works.

Being a newbie for vsto, I don't know where and how to delete all images. Any kind of assistance will be appreciated. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're trying to delete all images or all placeholders.They're 2 different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.shapes) property of the `Slide` class returns a `Shapes` collection that represents all the elements that have been placed or inserted on the specified slide, slide master, or range of slides. The [Shapes.Placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.placeholders) property returns a `Placeholders` collection that represents the collection of all the placeholders on a slide.

Try to use the following code:

```
Sub DeleteAllPictures()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim PPSlide As Slide
    For Each PPSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Dim PPShapes as powerPoint.Shapes = PPSlide.Shapes
        For Each PPPlaceholder In PPShapes.Placeholders
          PPPlaceholder.Delete
        Next  
    Next 
End Sub
```